# Caducidad luego de 24 horas Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla que recibe correos, esta tabla tiene como uno de sus atributos la fecha y hora

Necesito crear un procedimiento que al buscar en la tabla de correos si el correo llegara a tener mas de 24 horas de recibido pasa como un correo vencido

Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes pasar algún ejemplo demostrable de lo que quieres lograr? Porque esto también lo puedes hacer usando JOBS en SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendi correctamente tu consulta, te detallo un ejemplo que podria ayudarte.

```
/* Variable de tipo tabla para simular donde tienes los correos 
recibidos*/
DECLARE  @Mails  TABLE (mail VARCHAR(100),recibido DATETIME,vencido BIT)

/* completo con datos de prueba */
INSERT INTO @Mails SELECT 'mail1@mail.com',DATEADD(HOUR,-10, GETDATE()),0
INSERT INTO @Mails SELECT 'mail2@mail.com',DATEADD(HOUR,-12, GETDATE()),0
INSERT INTO @Mails SELECT 'mail3@mail.com',DATEADD(HOUR,-25, GETDATE()),0
INSERT INTO @Mails SELECT 'mail4@mail.com',DATEADD(HOUR,-30, GETDATE()),0

/* visualizacion de los datos insertados con el calculo de las horas desde 
la recepcion*/
SELECT *, HorasRecepcion = DATEDIFF(HOUR,recibido,GETDATE()) FROM @Mails

/* ACTUALIZO LOS QUE FUERON RECIBIDOS HACE MAS DE 23 HS*/
UPDATE @Mails SET vencido = 1 WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR,recibido,GETDATE()) >= 24

/* visualizacion de los datos actualizados */
SELECT * FROM @Mails
```

Comment: Exacto! Muchas gracias!!